# DataGridView выбор пользователем столбцов

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, datagridview, odbc

Вот такого хочется добиться, чтобы пользователь в **DataGrid(DataGridView)** сам выбирал какие поля ему нужны для работы. Данные формируются динамически как и названия столбцов из результата запроса. Используются **ODBC** драйвера для работы с базой. Вывод в **DataGrid(DataGridView)** делается следующим образом:

```
string sql="текст запроса";
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
OdbcDataAdapter myda = new OdbcDataAdapter(hytechsql,conn);
conn.Open();
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(hytechsql,conn);
myda.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource=dt;
conn.Close();
```

[image: Столбцы]

В общем получилось следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кнопки работают следующим образом:

//меняем местами кнопка +

```
        object item=listBox1.SelectedItem;
        int index=listBox1.SelectedIndex;
        int tempindex;
        if (index ==0||index<0)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            tempindex=index-1;
        object tempitem=listBox1.Items[tempindex];
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index);
        listBox1.Items.Insert(index, tempitem);
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(tempindex);
        listBox1.Items.Insert(tempindex, item);
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = tempindex;
```

кнопка -

```
        object item=listBox1.SelectedItem;
        int index=listBox1.SelectedIndex;
        int tempindex;
        if (index == listBox1.Items.Count - 1||index<0)
        {

        }
        else {
            tempindex=index+1;
        object tempitem=listBox1.Items[tempindex];
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index);
        listBox1.Items.Insert(index, tempitem);
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(tempindex);
        listBox1.Items.Insert(tempindex, item);
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = tempindex;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы не генерируете сами колонки, то элемент `DataGridView` делает это автоматически. После того, как он это сделал, сгенерированными колонками можно управлять.

При окончании генерации возникнет событие `DataBindingComplete`, после чего можно обратиться к коллекции `DataGridView.Columns` и управлять видимостью отдельной колонки через свойство `Visible`. Там же можно получить имена колонок для списка отображаемых и скрываемых.

Пример из [MSDN - DataGridView.DataBindingComplete Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender,
    DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    // Hide some of the columns.
    dataGridView1.Columns["EmployeeID"].Visible = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns["Address"].Visible = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns["TitleOfCourtesy"].Visible = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns["BirthDate"].Visible = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns["HireDate"].Visible = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns["PostalCode"].Visible = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns["Photo"].Visible = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns["Notes"].Visible = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns["ReportsTo"].Visible = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns["PhotoPath"].Visible = false;

    // Disable sorting for the DataGridView.
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn i in
        dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        i.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
    }

    dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
}
```

Принцип работы есть, остается только создать нужную форму и раскидать значения в зависимости от значения Visible и при закрытии изменить их. Для списка значений в форме я думаю подойдет простой ListBox.

Comment: Спасибо. Завтра опробую, не дошел чутка в msdn до этого метода. Отпишусь после теста.

Comment: Все отлично. Благодарю.